# How to read through object of server roles Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, discord, discord.js

I have the following code, which basically assigns a `RoleManager` object to the variable `roles`

```js
var roles = receivedMessage.guild.roles;
console.log(roles['cache']);
```

Now, the log returns some mess that (partially) looks like this:

```
Collection [Map] {
  '529502688183058443' => Role {
    guild: Guild {
      members: [GuildMemberManager],
      channels: [GuildChannelManager],
      roles: [RoleManager],
      presences: [PresenceManager],
      voiceStates: [VoiceStateManager],
      deleted: false,
      available: true,
      id: '529502688183058443',
      shardID: 0,
      name: 'GuyDyamond Studios',
      icon: '36e1f32f9fc98818872ca4583d50cc52',
      splash: null,
      discoverySplash: null,
      region: 'us-east',
      memberCount: 6,
      large: false,
      features: [],
      applicationID: null,
      afkTimeout: 300,
      afkChannelID: null,
      systemChannelID: '529502688183058445',
      embedEnabled: undefined,
      premiumTier: 0,
      premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
      verificationLevel: 'MEDIUM',
      explicitContentFilter: 'DISABLED',
      mfaLevel: 0,
      joinedTimestamp: 1600020773558,
      defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
      systemChannelFlags: [SystemChannelFlags],
      maximumMembers: 250000,
      vanityURLCode: null,
      vanityURLUses: null,
      description: null,
      banner: null,
      rulesChannelID: null,
      publicUpdatesChannelID: null,
      preferredLocale: 'en-US',
      ownerID: '423162345108275213',
      emojis: [GuildEmojiManager]
    },
    id: '529502688183058443',
    name: '@everyone',
    color: 0,
    hoist: false,
    rawPosition: 0,
    permissions: Permissions { bitfield: 104324673 },
    managed: false,
    mentionable: false,
    deleted: false
  },
  '529672467200081922' => Role {
    guild: Guild {
      members: [GuildMemberManager],
      channels: [GuildChannelManager],
      roles: [RoleManager],
      presences: [PresenceManager],
      voiceStates: [VoiceStateManager],
      deleted: false,
      available: true,
      id: '529502688183058443',
      shardID: 0,
      name: 'GuyDyamond Studios',
      icon: '36e1f32f9fc98818872ca4583d50cc52',
      splash: null,
      discoverySplash: null,
      region: 'us-east',
      memberCount: 6,
      large: false,
      features: [],
      applicationID: null,
      afkTimeout: 300,
      afkChannelID: null,
      systemChannelID: '529502688183058445',
      embedEnabled: undefined,
      premiumTier: 0,
      premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
      verificationLevel: 'MEDIUM',
      explicitContentFilter: 'DISABLED',
      mfaLevel: 0,
      joinedTimestamp: 1600020773558,
      defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
      systemChannelFlags: [SystemChannelFlags],
      maximumMembers: 250000,
      vanityURLCode: null,
      vanityURLUses: null,
      description: null,
      banner: null,
      rulesChannelID: null,
      publicUpdatesChannelID: null,
      preferredLocale: 'en-US',
      ownerID: '423162345108275213',
      emojis: [GuildEmojiManager]
    },
```

Now, I've literally tried everything, but I can't seem to iterate over the object `roles`. I've tried a `forEach` function, a `for...in...` loop, etc etc, nothing. Additionally, I'm trying to get the name of each role and put it in an array, but I can't seem to get the `name` parameter. Any help on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is the names, you can use `Array.prototype.map`:

```js
console.log(
  recievedMessage.guild.roles.cache.map((role) => role.name)
);
```

---

Example result:

```js
['Admin', 'Mod', 'VIP', 'Member', 'Muted', '@everyone']
```

---

To iterate a function through every role, use:

```js
recievedMessage.guild.roles.cache.forEach((role) => {
  console.log(role.id);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This does indeed work. I didn't think of iterating through the cache instead of the entire roles. Thanks!!!